# Error getting valueForKey in an NSDictionary for key containing @ character

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am trying to get the value of "@type" key in the following NSDictionary named 'robotDesign'

```
robotDesign : {
    "@id" = "2";
    "@type" = "piggyDash";
    turnAngle = "-90";
    width = "90.0";
}
```

that is a part of a JSON object I got using

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: options: error:];
```

I am using following code to extract @type value

```
NSString * robot_type = (NSString*)[robotDesign valueForKey:@"@type"];
```

but recive following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<__NSCFDictionary 0x71de9e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type.'

**NOTE:** Please note that other objects in dictionary like 'turnAngle' and 'width' are extracted easily using same code given above but with their respective keys.

Comment: That's why it's stupid to use valueForKey and not objectForKey. Best case, valueForKey spends useless time to figure out that it can call objectForKey. Worst case, you get rubbish. For example valueForKey:@"@count" will give you the number of key/value pairs in the dictionary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
NSString * robot_type = [robotDesign objectForKey:@"@type"];
```

or remove the leading `@`

[from the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ)

> `valueForKey:`
>   Returns the value associated with a given key.
>
> `- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key`
>    **Parameters** key The key for which to return the corresponding value. Note that when using key-value coding,
>   the key must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”).
>
> **Return Value**
>   The value associated with key.
>
> **Discussion** If key does not start with “@”, invokes objectForKey:. If
>   key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes [super
>   valueForKey:] with the rest of the key.

The `@` leads to call the implementation of the `valueForKey:` of the superclass of NSDictionary. But NSObject does not know anything about the key `type`.

Comment: Thanks @viki for your answer. The line of code you wrote above did work but I don't understand why. I did read the above mentioned 'Discussion' in docs but I guess the @ referred to in it is the @ preceding the "" not the @ within the "". Can you explain please so that I can mark your answer correct. Thanks.

Comment: while in `objectForKey:` @ is just part of the String, it is interpreted as an operator in the `valueForKey:` check apples docs for Key Value Coding to learn about it.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, a minor correction.  The problem is not that `NSObject` doesn't have a key (property) called `type`; the problem is that `NSDictionary` doesn't either.  The purpose of `NSDictionary` overriding the method is to give code a way to access a property of `NSDictionary` that is *also* a key in the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly documented behavior. From [NSDictionary's class reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> NSDictionary overrides the 'valueForKey:' method. If the key starts with an '@' character, it invokes super, else it invokes objectForKey:

So, unless you have a valid reason for not doing so, you should use `- objectForKey:`.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly documented behaviour. It's also very easily glossed over behaviour which is why @shaffooo has encountered it.

Comment: No, just use objectForKey.