# JSON Value for key is starting with@

Tags: objective-c, json

I have the json response like below:

```
  "hj.tradingResponse" =     {
    "@approved" = true;
    "@qualified" = true;
    billingAddress =         {
        address = "146 W. Main Street";
        city = Aguilar;
        country = US;
        postalCode = 81020;
        state = Colorado;
    };
```

I stored a result in a dictionary. Byt when I give value for key `[result valueForKey:@"\"@approved\""];`

I'm getting null value but I thought `@approved` is not recognising.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That's some nice invalid JSON you've got there.

Comment: What language is `[result valueForKey:@"\"@approved\""];` ?

Comment: You might want to use http://jsonlint.com to check all your JSON to be sure it's valid.

Comment: That looks like Objective-C. Tag added.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, the quotes themselves are not part of the key.

Try

```
[result valueForKey:@"@approved"]
```

Comment: Better use `objectForKey`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294696/error-getting-valueforkey-in-an-nsdictionary-for-key-containing-character.