# Error while Getting Values from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am tring to get value from an NSDictionary but getting an Exception that the keys is not defined.

```
NSDictionary *userNames=[[NSDictionary alloc] init]; 
NSString * testValue = @"";
testValue = [userNames valueForKey:@"@&"];//crashing here when key is @&
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<__NSDictionaryM 0x2831eeec0> valueForUndefinedKey:]

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: You have to provide complete declaration of NSDictionary. One suggestion is to use NSDictionary *usernames = @{......}, where @ is missing before '{'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  I updated the question, can you check it

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294696/error-getting-valueforkey-in-an-nsdictionary-for-key-containing-character

Answer (score 4):

**Never** use `valueForKey` to get a single value from a dictionary unless you know what KVC is and you really need KVC.

The dictionary is empty, the key does not exist and the leading `@` has a special meaning in KVC so `valueForKey` crashes in this case.

The proper API is `objectForKey` but just use modern key subscripting to get at least `nil` if the key doesn't exist

```
testValue = userNames[@"@&"];
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1410210-value)

> If key does not start with “@”, invokes object(forKey:). If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes [super valueForKey:] with the rest of the key.

you may do

`testValue = [userNames objectForKey:@"@&"]`

or

`testValue = [userNames valueForKey:@"&"]`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not declaring keys and values. NSDictionary requires you to init with Values and keys. (Whether fetch them from a file or declare them while initializing.

```
NSDictionary * userNames = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"value1", @"key1",
                            @"value2", @"key2",
                            nil];

NSString * testValue = [userNames valueForKey:@"key2"];
NSLog(@"%@", testValue);
```

Also notice that the value is written before and then key is defined. Refer to this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574190-initwithobjectsandkeys?language=objc).

If you want to declare the dictionary first (like you did in your question) and then add the values and keys to the dictionary, You have to use NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userNames1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userNames1 setValue:@"firstValue" forKey:@"key1"];
[userNames1 setValue:@"secondValue" forKey:@"key2"];

NSLog(@"%@", [userNames1 valueForKey:@"key2"]);
```